# What does the sum of random variables represent?

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, means

For random variables $X_1, ..., X_N (N = 100)$ such that each of their means are $0.1$ and $Y = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i = 1}^NX_i$, how is the mean of $Y$ meant to be calculated? I don't really understand what $Y$ represents here; what does a sum of variables represent?

My intuition tells me that the expected value of $Y$ is simply the mean of means, which would thus be $0.1$, but I must be missing something conceptually because it's not all clear to me. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable $Y$ is some random variable because it is a sum of some other random variables. To understand this conceptually: Imagine that you were rolling $N$ dice, with the outcome of each rolled die be $X_1,\cdots,X_N$ and the average of all the outcomes of the rolls were $Y$. Clearly you wouldn't know the average value $Y$ unless all the dies were revealed to you. So $Y$ is some random variable, at least conceptually. Get it?

As $Y$ is a random variable, it must have some probability distribution, but it is often unclear exactly what distribution it is, unless we knew specific things about the properties of the $X_i$. In this case you know that they all have expected value $0.1$, and as $Y$ is also a random variable it must have some expected value, which is most easily calculated using the "linearity property" of expected value, namely that
$E(aX_i + bX_j) = aE(X_i) + bE(X_j)$ if $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. By using this property multiple times you get
$$E(Y) = E (\frac{1}{N}\sum_i^N X_i) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_i^N E (X_i)$$ 
Now since you know that $E(X_i) = 0.1$ we must have $E(Y) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_i^N 0.1 =  \frac{1}{N}N 0.1 = 0.1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; that makes a lot of sense! I was wondering, though: from this, how does one get the variance of Y? I've done the math, and the variance of Y is $\frac{1}{N}Var(X)$. Is that the closest I can get with the information I have? Thanks.

Comment: It is difficult to get the variance of $Y$ unless you know that the random variables are independent. In that case, it is easy because $\mathrm{Var}(aX_i + bX_j) = a^2\mathrm{Var}(X_i) + b^2 \mathrm{Var}(X_j)$. With your information you cannot get the variance unless you know the variance of each random variable.

Comment: Sorry, they are in independent and identically distributed; I forgot to mention that. But in this case, I simply get that $Var(Y) = \frac{1}{N}Var(X) = \frac{1}{N}(Var(X^2) - (Var(X))^2)$. How am I meant to find $Var(X^2)$ when I know nothing else about the variables?

Comment: No. The formula is $\mathrm{Var}(X) = E(X^2)-E(X)^2$. So they have to tell you some more info, for example $E(X_i^2)$ or the variance of $X_i$ if you were to solve it. Note that in general $E(X_i^2) \neq 0.1^2$